# Scraping multiple tables from a single webpage in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, rvest

I would like to scrape **multiple tables from this webpage** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Euro_2020_squads). The table that I needed is from [1] - Italy to [23] - Portugal where it contains the player's list for each team participating in Euro 2020.

Below are my codes.

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

wiki_euro20_link <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Euro_2020_squads"
wiki_euro20_page <- read_html(wiki_euro20_link)

eur_20 <- wiki_euro20_page %>% 
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  html_table() %>%
  .[c(1:24)]

purrr::map(eur_20[-1], dplyr::bind_rows)
```

The question is:

- How do I **combine all the tables in one dataframe**?

Comment: `result <- dplyr::bind_rows(eur_20[-1])`

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you for your help kind sir!